# How to make Prometheus check all the ports of a Docker container running on Marathon?

Tags: prometheus

I have a Docker container, exposing more than 2 ports, running on Marathon. I am using Marathon SD configuration in Prometheus configuration file to identify the targets as follows:

```
marathon_sd_configs:
- servers:
  - 'http://A.B.X.Y:Z'#Marathon URL
```

But, Prometheus always seems to check only one of the exposed ports(the first port number in Marathon app definition) as a target and shows that target's state as 'Down' though I have metrics available on one of the other exposed ports(verified by using 'static_config' in Prometheus). How to make Prometheus check other ports too and identify the actual target port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by the Prometheus community.

Issue link: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2448

Merged pull request to consider all the ports of a Marathon task as targets: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/2506